# React hook not setting state until click submit button twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

For some reason, a state is not being set until clicking on the submit button twice when submitting my form. Here is my state:

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
  isSuccess: false,
  isFailed: false,
  alertMsg: '',
  userId: '',
  firstName: '',
  lastName: '',
  email: ''
});
```

Here is my `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setState({
    ...state,
    firstName: user.first_name,
    lastName: user.last_name,
    email: user.email
  })
}, [user.first_name, user.last_name, user.email]);
```

Here is the function using on input change:

```
const onInputChange = (e) => {
  e.persist();
  setState({...state, [e.target.name as string]: e.target.value});
}
```

Here is the function using when updating the DB:

```
const onUpdateUser = () => {
  const updateUserInfo = {
    first_name: state.firstName,
    last_name: state.lastName,
    email: state.email
  }

  const res = dispatch(updateUser(updatedUserInfo));

  if(res.ok) {
    setState({
      ...state,
      isSuccess: true,
      alertMsg: 'User information updated successfully!'
    })
  } else {
    setState({
      ...state,
      isFailed: true,
      alertMsg: 'User information update failed!'
    })
  }
}
```

The success/failed alerts don't appear unless I click the submit button twice. What's weird is if I have `isSuccess, isFailed, alertMsg` separately, it works perfectly. For example:

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
  userId: '',
  firstName: '',
  lastName: '',
  email: ''
});

const [isSuccess, setIsSuccess] = useState(false);
const [isFailed, setIsFailed] = useState(false);
const [alertMsg, setAlertMsg] = useState('');
```

Doing the above works beautifully. If there is no way of having it all in one, I just want to know why. Was trying to keep everything as clean as possible.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Every time any of the state keys change everything is going to rerender again, so probably your effect runs with stale data. you can probably fix this by using the setState callback `setState(s => ..new values here..)` instead of passing an object directly but honestly if you want to have all your state in a single object `useReducer` makes a lot more sense

Comment: Did you tried to place an `useEffect` to listen to the `state.isSuccess` or `state.isError` separately?
Now you have an `useEffect` to listen to any changes on your `user.first_name`, `user.last_name` and `user.email`. What about to place an additional `useEffect` to listen to success or error? When those states have changes, so you can decide to show the error or success messages

Comment: @azium, I don't really understand what you mean. @Camilo Silva, I tried that, and still doesn't work. What did work was moving `isSuccess, isFailed, isAlert` to its own state which I set as `const [alert, setAlert] = useState(...)`

Comment: When you do `setState({ ...state, whatever })` the value of `state` is the "old closure" state and your async state is probably getting obliterated by the old closure state. read this article it will save you tons of aggravation http://www.cristo.top/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/